# What's the best way to make a Ruby on Rails helper for your secure url path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I come from a PHP and Python/GAE background and am new to RoR.  Typically I'd have a global variable set up containing my unsecure and secure webpage's url, for use when templating.  For example, if I want to link to an image, rather than saying img src="www.mysite.com/images/img1.png" I can use img src="{{ unsecure_url }}images/img1.png".

I'm thinking the best way to do this in RoR is to add the following to my application_helper.  Is that valid?

```
def unsecure_url
  "http://localhost:3000/"
end

def secure_url
  "https://localhost:3000/"
end
```

And how can I switch between localhost and production, depending on whether I'm in a local environment or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the pre-existing helpers, they should generate relative links for the current protocol and domain.

Take a look at [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), and [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).